# output image in php page

Tags: php, html, image, display

[image]

thank you so much for your hard work, 
my issue hopefully is not that complicated. 
I'm trying to display few images in my website, and it won't display, 
the php page and the image are on the same directory, and when i try the same directory on html file it works fine, but when I try to use the same directory on php file the pic look broken icon,and won't appear.. 
I also tried png and jpg image, still nothing coming out..

please guys..

this is the simple code, i tried to test,

```
    <html>
<head><title> hello </title></head>
<body>
<?php $image = 'zz.png'; ?>

<img src= "<?php $image ?>" style="width:304px;height:228px;">


hello world.. 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `<img src= "<?php echo $image; ?>`

Comment: also, dont use inline css for img tags. use `width="304" height="228"` instead

Comment: or, alternatively : `<?=$image?>`, which is a shortcut of `<?php echo $image; ?>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print the var `$image` with [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) (and close the image tag with a frontslash at the end of the tag for correct html):

`<img src= "<?php echo $image; ?>" style="width:304px;height:228px;" />`

Other possible reasons the image is not displayed (after you print the image name out with `echo`):

- the value of your var `$image` mismatched with  the imagename.
- the image is not stored in the same folder as the php document.
- your image is saved in `CMYK` mode, and not in `RGB`.
- the file permission of the image
- configuration of the webserver (apache for ex.)

Comment: thank u, i did as u said, still nothing showing ? u can please write en example that u tested.

Comment: @aymanko is the image stored in the same folder as the php-document? Perhaps try the developertools of your fav. browser to evaluate what's going wrong.

Comment: yes, they r in the same folder, and when I convert the file to html file the image works fine. but when i use php ,it won't come out

Comment: @aymanko did you use a webserver (with php support) to request your php document? How the html source code (in your browser) looks like?

Comment: I'm using XAMPP, to run my php on a local server.

Comment: by ur second part in ur question, do u mean u want to see my html code ?

Comment: @aymanko yes, to check that the php interpreter works correctly... (and you open the docuement correctly). You URL should start with `http://localhost/..` (if you didn't edit your hosts file)

Comment: yes, when I edit the url to http://localhost/ it shows in the url bar as shown in the pic..

Comment: @aymanko Use your screenshot image for a test ... (: This ist stored in RGB. Are you able to access it direct in the browser, like: `http://localhost/zz.png`

Comment: oh, It test ur code, and it says Access forbidden! ?

Comment: Access forbidden!
Error 403

Comment: @aymanko ok, then something with xampp (apache) config seems to be wrong. Best start a new question. Have a look in your apache config, or if there is a `.htaccess` file in this folder, check this...

Comment: I got it fixed man, it was the permission issue.. in the image properties..
but THANK U SO MUCH sir, for ur big hint,,

Answer (score 1):

You have to print out the `$image` variable by using the [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) function. Your code should be looking like this:

```
<?php
    $image = 'zz.png';
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> hello </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src= "<?php echo $image; ?>" style="width:304px;height:228px;">

    hello world.. 
    </body>
</html>
```

Furthermore, it looks better when you put all your php stuff before the HTML code, that does not necessarily have to be inside HTML.

If it is still not working, you are probably viewing your html file locally. You have to view it remotely by using a http web server with a php interpreter included. You can easily set up one with [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html).

Remember that it does not work by just opening your file in a browser.

Comment: I appreciate ur answer Sir, but it's still not displaying.. ?!

Comment: <img src= "<?php echo $image; ?>" width="304" height="228" ">
I used this line, yet nothing coming out..

Comment: What kind of http server do you use?

Comment: Can you tell us what the output is, when you try to access it?

Comment: it shows u a blank pic with a small little broken icon on the corner of it. .signify that there is an image but its not appearing..

Comment: I added an image, of the result

Comment: I tested my code and it worked. Please ensure that the name of the file is zz.png, and check the case sensitivity (could it be ZZ.png or zz.PNG?) and check the file extension (is it really .png or is it .jpg?)

Comment: no, the code exactly what I've been running, and name of the image still the same. zz.png  all lowercase. 
is it like the Setting in XAMPP ?? maybe ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace this line:

```
<img src= "<?php $image ?>" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
```

With this:

```
<img src= "<?php echo($image) ?>" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
```

Since echo() is the function that generates the output.

Comment: thank u sir, but it's still not showing, would u please please put a code that u tested, and works on ur php file

Comment: I missed the ;

Try this:

    <img src= "<?php echo($image); ?>" style="width:304px;height:228px;">