# How to display an image on my page instead of pathname

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch image on my page but it's showing pathname instead, below is my code.

```
<td><?= $items['id']; ?></td>
<td><?= $items['fullname']; ?></td>
<td><?= $items['phone_no']; ?></td>
<td><?= $items['<img src="picture" />']; ?></td>
```

Here is the full code:

[image]

Comment: Using PHP?  Could you post 50 lines on each side of this code so we get some sense of your task complexity?

Comment: Here is the full code: https://pasteboard.co/U3u6Q4fU4hv7.jpg

Comment: This URL may lead you to success.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042196/output-image-in-php-page  
Thanks for the 'full code'  Let us know in a day or so if you have mastered the task, please.  And post your successful code, please.

Comment: The code below works just fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some sort of mix up there. I gather that $items is an array. So you should give a key name to the image item, not the source you want to print. Store the path in (for example) `$items['picture']` then you just echo the path inside the src attribute of an image element.

```
<td><?= $items['id']; ?></td>
<td><?= $items['fullname']; ?></td>
<td><?= $items['phone_no']; ?></td>
<td><img src="<?= $items['picture']; ?>"></td>
```

Comment: Thanks, after pasting this code this is the output: https://pasteboard.co/wHs0iuKPFZ1l.jpg meanwhile I want the picture to show the image preview

Comment: Can you echo $items['picture'] on its own to see what's the value? You might have to add the rest of the path like https ://yourwebsite.com/pathtoimage/....

Comment: You're too much, your code works like magic, when I moved the image into the root folder it loads perfectly, but when i move the image back to the image folder the output is like this: pasteboard.co/wHs0iuKPFZ1l.jpg . Please how will I write to code to make it fetch picture from image folder in the root?

Comment: Does this work? `<td><img src="image/<?= $items['picture']; ?>"></td>` ?

Comment: Format them using style="width: 888px; height 666px; object-fit: cover;" You can use any CSS formatting or size you want really.

Comment: You guys are awesome!!! You just save me a lot of time... Merci.